# Show alias for method in IntelliSense in TypeScript as method instead of property

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

I trying to create a class in TypeScript in Visual Studio 2013 with method `func1` with alias `func1_Alias` and show both in IntelliSense as methods, but IntelliSense shows alias as property instead of method. I can't found a way to show my alias `func1_Alias` as method in IntelliSense except:

```
func1_alias(...args:any[]){
   return this.func1.call(this, args);
}
```

But this way creates another function instead of using the same function. It's mean that `func1 === func1_Alias => false`.

[image: IntelliSense for function]
[image: IntelliSense for property]

Comment: Its not about the type of the thing but rather where it lives on the class definition. It is a property.

Answer (score 2):

`func1_alias` *is* a property, not a method. It lives on the instance of the class, not the prototype. There isn't a way to tell Intellisense to lie about what the type of the object is.